# If you're storing an image Blob in App Engine, should you put it in the Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

[Google Cloud Storage](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/getting-started.html) seems more cost effective than the **App Engine Blobstore**.

At the moment I am storing user-uploaded image files as `Blob` type fields in the **Datastore** (App Engine Java API, by the way).

But I'm debating whether to switch to either the **Blobstore** or **Google Cloud Storage** to permit image sizes greater than 1MB.

**Google Cloud Storage** seems more cost-effective than **Blobstore**. Which one would be better for storing large images?

Comment: Blobstore costs $0.15/gb/mo, while Developer Storage costs $0.13/gb/mo. Is it really worth making a design decision over $0.02/gb/mo?

Comment: As of today, Blobstore is $0.13/GiB/mo and Cloud Storage starts at either $0.085/GiB/mo or $0.063/GiB/mo. Pricing docs here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing and https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricingandterms#pricing

Comment: As of today (13-Feb-2016), they are priced the same: 0.026 per Gib/mo.  Quite  a drop in pricing over the past couple of years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Blobstore is tightly integrated with App Engine, while Cloud Storage is offered stand-alone. Otherwise, they look like different interfaces to the same basic service.

I don't see any good technical reason for them to be priced differently; perhaps it's a marketing thing.

The Blobstore has a more mature API and does some neat stuff like making thumbnails on the fly without incurring extra storage. The Cloud Storage API is [experimental and rapidly changing](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/). They're both perfectly capable of storing large images. To choose, you'll need to decide if the Blobstore's more rubust API justifies the nominally higher cost.

Comment: Are there any differences in terms of latency/access times?

Answer (score 3):

Well, As of Dec 19 2014 It looks like GCS is the way to go. stated on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage#alternative_storage_solutions

Google Cloud Storage is recommended over using the Blobstore API.

Answer (score 2):

I try to give a different answer. I would suggest **Picasa** as the image storage in common situation.

I ran into the same question when Google stopped to serve Google Storage for free. 
But then I noticed that [Picasa is free for pictures smaller than 2048x2048 when your Google plus account is enabled](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1224181). And it's still more cost-effective for paid-storage.

So if you are going to store small pictures like profile pictures, I would suggest App Engine Blobstore.
If you are dealing with some more photos and pictures, take a look at Picasa.

Answer (score 2):

Note that with the latest release, there's now [an API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/) for accessing Cloud Storage from App Engine.