# Blobstore or Cloud Storage for store photo

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstorage

I design an mobile app which can upload photo on GAE.
These photos **can not be changed**, **only displayed** on other mobiles. Through my application, the picture will be sent only on GAE, and downloaded to the mobile clients. That's all!

I only use GAE for store photos, and datastore for store photo's data string (Like position, age...)

Do you think I have to go on the Cloud Storage (Because I would be locked after a while?), or I can stay on the Blobstore ?

I fear that in the future the Blobstore was deprecated..

Thanks !

Comment: Blobstore will not be deprecated, if later you feel that your storage is exceeding 5GB free storage, then you can go for the paid. Also I suggest you to use ImageService API as well to serve your images with a faster response time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blobstore vs. Cloud Storage is an ongoing debate. check out these resources:

[Google Blobstore versus Google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671182/google-blobstore-versus-google-cloud-storage)

[If you're storing an image Blob in App Engine, should you put it in the Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753840/if-youre-storing-an-image-blob-in-app-engine-should-you-put-it-in-the-blobstor?rq=1)

[Comparing Blobstore and Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175510/comparing-blobstore-and-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: I already see this answers, but I cant make my choice.. =( I need very sample storage (Just for photo) but secured. I think BlobStore is the good solution no ?

Comment: It sounds like blobstore will be simpler for you. Just make a choice and start coding :-)

Comment: I think so ! Thanks for your answers ! I'm beginner in JAVA and Android developpement, so it's a little bit hard all this things for me =)

Comment: Since GAE 1.9.x things have changed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Use GCS because:

- Google is moving away from the blobstore
- GCS offers more functionality like acl, folders, and more.
- You can use filenames and a blobstore like serving url for images
- You can create serving url's for non images
- GCS is cheap and has a free default bucket

Comment: I find blobstore easier than GCS for coding. I'm beginner on java and Android, and I can't find any informations to how upload photo on GCS from Android device.. So to begin, I think I use Blobstore, and I migrate later !

Comment: you upload the GCS the same way that you upload to blobstore. If it's a new project you really want to be using GCS.

Comment: But why ? GCS bring more functionnality that I dont really need, so.. If I choose GCS only just is better (without any technical explanation), I think I will continue to use blobstore.. =| But thanks for your answer ! =D

Answer (score 0):

Relative to Google itself, there no good reasons to use blobstore to store files because Cloud Storage is made to do this.

I think Google will deprecate the Blobstore soon...

Comment: Re-thanks Maël (It's Philippe, Sciences-U). I will hope that blobstore will be better than GSC (Because easier and my code work on blobstore, but no for GCS)..  Choose easier solution is not the best way I think.. I will try to use GCS with android, maybe with your help Maël.. Thanks again for your help =)

Comment: Here a sample code for Java : http://bit.ly/1jcmlGk
The eclipse project : http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/storage-serviceaccount-appengine-sample/instructions.html

Comment: Tanks ! I will see that :-)